# Saving and retrieving date in Firebase

Tags: java, android, date, firebase

I have a model with the following structure

```
public class OfferModel {
    private String mImageUrl;
    private String mOfferCode;
    private String mOfferTitle;
    private String mOfferDescription;
    private boolean mIsRunning;
    private String mCreatorUid;
    private Date mStartDate;
}
```

Everything else works fine on saving. It saves in Firebase Realtime database as

```
startDate
    date: 22
    day: 3
    hours: 23
    minutes: 20
    month: 5
    seconds: 50
    time: 1466617850476
    timezoneOffset: -330
    year: 116
```

But when I try to retrieve it, the date gives the following error -

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: java.util.HashMap cannot be cast to java.util.Date
at com.localvine.models.OfferModel.<init>(OfferModel.java:37)
at com.localvine.managers.OfferManager$1.onDataChange(OfferManager.java:62)
at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzafp.zza(Unknown Source)
at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzagp.zzSu(Unknown Source)
at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzags$1.run(Unknown Source)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
```

I understand that Firebase doesn't support Java Date object, but since it's saving them in a map, how can I get back the date from that map? Is there any proper way of saving and retrieving dates in Firebase Android?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You can store the date as an epoch date. It's a long that you can get using your system time `System.currentTimeMillis();` or by using the Firebase server time with their `ServerValue.TIMESTAMP`. The thing with the first option is that it changes with timezones and system settings. So if you store the date as a long, you just have to change your `OfferModel` field `mStartDate` to a `long` and then use `new Date(long)` to get the corresponding `Date` when retrieving the object.

Comment: Actually, epoch time is the number of seconds since Jan 1 1970 UTC; What you are suggesting is to use the number of milliseconds

Answer (score 14):

**Use [ISO 8601 date format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10286204/the-right-json-date-format)**:

```
SimpleDateFormat ISO_8601_FORMAT = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:sss'Z'");

String now = ISO_8601_FORMAT.format(new Date());
```

Representing `Date` as a `String` has two greater advantages:

- It is human readable (`"2018-03-30T13:18:39.516Z"` vs `1522415925281`)
- At the browser side, you can simply invokes `new Date("2018-03-30T13:18:39.516Z")`

This is quite useful if you have Android and browsers both consuming Firebase data.

Comment: In my case the pattern appeared to be ```yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'```

Comment: Be aware that you disable the right to perform range queries if you do this. There's a reason why many databases store date as millisecond time format.

Comment: @OliverDixon, Are you sure that range queries get disabled if we store time as ISO strings? I thought they are just strings, and have the right characteristics for sorting in the correct order if we treat them as strings.

I've been sorting ISO date strings and assuming it was OK. Haven't tried database range queries on them but is there a limitation?

Comment: Data(java.lang.String) is deprecated as of API 16. And it gives me an **FATAL EXCEPTION**: `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
        at java.util.Date.parse(Date.java:638)
        at java.util.Date.<init>(Date.java:274)`

Comment: One issue with doing this is comparing the current time for data that's come in with different timezones is complex.

Answer (score 6):

This is how I managed to store Date on Firebase by using the SimpleDateFormat to convert it to only a date without seconds, hours or milliseconds.

```
public void storeDatetoFirebase() {

    handler = new Handler();

    runnable = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            handler.postDelayed(this, 1000);
            try {
                Date date = new Date();
                Date newDate = new Date(date.getTime() + (604800000L * 2) + (24 * 60 * 60));
                SimpleDateFormat dt = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
                String stringdate = dt.format(newDate);

                System.out.println("Submission Date: " + stringdate);
                DatabaseReference databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("My_Date");
                databaseReference.child("init_date").setValue(stringdate);

            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    };
    handler.postDelayed(runnable, 1 * 1000);
}
```

and this is how it appears on Firebase:

[image: Date onFirebase]

Hope it helps..

Comment: cleanest way! thaks

Answer (score 3):

Although firebase does support Date format datatype, I would prefer to save date-time in a string format, because by storing it as a string it becomes quite easy to retrieve it.

To store current system date-time in a string format just below code will do.

```
        DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss");
        Date date = new Date();
        String strDate = dateFormat.format(date).toString();
        myRef.child("datetime").setValue(strDate);
```

Now one can use the strDate to store in the firebase or do whatever one want to do with that string.

Comment: Great plan! Even better to use ISO date format, so it will be even more painless to inter-operate with other systems etc. e.g. `2018-12-16T23:03:53Z` https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601

Answer (score -1):

you can set a date object on Firebase

```
yourReference.setValue(new Date());
```

It works, But

I noticed other PROBLEM with the date, when i changed the month manually from the db, when retrieving it the value stays as before

Comment: Welcome to SO ! but this is not an answer to post, but instead you can comment it :)