# Increment value in the database by one every day

Tags: java, android, firebase, logical-operators

My question might be really simple but i will appreciate any help, am using java and firebase and i have a variable in the database called count == 0, i need to increment this value every day by 1, so after 30 days the variable count should be count == 30, the only trouble is making that increment  programmaticaly.

Any suggestions will be highly appreciated.

Comment: `UPDATE MY_TABLE SET COUNT = (COUNT +1) WHERE ID = 1234`

Comment: Have some scheduling task run this every day

Comment: What solution have you already tried, and why didn't that solution satisfy you?

Comment: So you want to execute a task (in your case, incrementing a number in a database) daily. I'd suggest searching for topics like "android schedule job" (or task)

Comment: How about storing a `created_at` using `System.currentTimeMillis()` and then calculate the time from `created_at` to `Instant.now()` in days? No scheduling that can fail, no counter that can be manipulated... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37976468/saving-and-retrieving-date-in-firebase

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A [scheduled Cloud Function deployed with the Firebase CLI](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/schedule-functions) will be the proper way to update your data in firebase. Your can run a scheduled function which can be triggered at a specific time (everyday or week however you want) and you can update your variable in the database inside the function. Here is a sample from firebase official documentation :

```js
exports.scheduledFunctionCrontab = functions.pubsub.schedule('5 11 * * *')
  .timeZone('America/New_York') // Users can choose timezone - default is America/Los_Angeles
  .onRun((context) => {
  console.log('This will be run every day at 11:05 AM Eastern!');
  return null;
});
```

Read documentation here : https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/schedule-functions#write_a_scheduled_function

Comment: FYI on Stack Overflow, backtick quotes are used to mark snippets of code, not for highlighting product names.